# Getting a list of all fields in an object

Tags: java, strings, reflection

I've got the following code that I use to output a list of all (public) fields in an object in an easy(ish) to read way. The issue with it is that the code is not easy to look at, and I'm not sure what I could do to improve it.

I'm not too fond of all of the StringBuilders, the `append` calls are ugly and chaining them does not help the situation however I can't see a better way of doing it.

```
public abstract class Component {
    private String[] getFields() {
        Class<? extends Component> componentClass = getClass();
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Field field: componentClass.getFields()) {
            StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            lineBuilder.append(field.getName());

            field.setAccessible(true);

            try {
                Object value = field.get(this);

                lineBuilder.append(" = ");
                lineBuilder.append(value);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                lineBuilder.append(" > ");
                lineBuilder.append(e.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }

            lines.add(lineBuilder.toString());
        }

        return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(getClass().getSimpleName());
        boolean firstIteration = true;

        builder.append('(');

        for (String field: getFields()) {
            if (!firstIteration) {
                builder.append(", ");
            } else {
                firstIteration = false;
            }

            builder.append(field);
        }

        builder.append(')');

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why I separated `getFields` into it's own method, however it might be better to move it back into `toString`.

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you can do:

```
private String[] getFields() {
    Class<? extends Component> componentClass = getClass();
    Field[] fields = componentClass.getFields();
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(fields.length);

    Arrays.stream(fields).forEach(field -> {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            lines.add(field.getName() + " = " + field.get(this));
        } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
            lines.add(field.getName() + " > " + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    });

    return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
}
```

or to improve formatting:

```
private String[] getFields() {
    Class<? extends Component> componentClass = getClass();
    Field[] fields = componentClass.getFields();
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(fields.length);

    Arrays.stream(fields)
            .forEach(
                    field -> {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        try {
                            lines.add(field.getName() + " = " + field.get(this));
                        } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
                            lines.add(field.getName() + " > "
                                    + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
                        }
                    });

    return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
}
```

Note that this is adding to @EricStein's excellent answer on normal concatenation instead of `StringBuilder`s.

(I'm just starting to look into `Streams`, so if this is bad, please comment on why)

Otherwise...

Just a small comment:

> ```
> lineBuilder.append(" = ");
> lineBuilder.append(value);
> ```

can easily be:

```
lineBuilder.append(" = ").append(value);
```

Same with:

> ```
> lineBuilder.append(" > ");
> lineBuilder.append(e.getClass().getSimpleName());
> ```

becomes:

```
lineBuilder.append(" > ").append(e.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Also, I would use a simple array instead of an `ArrayList`:

```
private String[] getFields() {
    Class<? extends Component> componentClass = getClass();
    Field[] fields = componentClass.getFields();
    String[] lines = new String[fields.length];

    int index = 0;
    for (Field field : fields) {
        StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        lineBuilder.append(field.getName());

        field.setAccessible(true);

        try {
            Object value = field.get(this);

            lineBuilder.append(" = ");
            lineBuilder.append(value);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            lineBuilder.append(" > ");
            lineBuilder.append(e.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }

        lines[index++] = lineBuilder.toString();
    }

    return lines;
}
```

**EDIT:** The above review, if not using Java 8, should be replaced by @EricStein's code.

Also, `getFields()` is a bad name. Try `getFieldDescriptions()`.

Comment: "and chaining them does not help the situation"

Comment: @EricStein I know, but it is easier to read and type (at least for me).

Comment: So your solution is to tell him to do something he's already tried and rejected as being not helpful?

Comment: @EricStein He has rejected it as being not helpful, but I am trying to say it can be helpful. `StringBuilder`'s `append()` method returns itself for a reason. Also I added to my answer.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(fields).stream()` -> `Arrays.stream()`.

Comment: @h.j.k thanks for the comment, will remember in the future :)

Comment: Streams are meant to filter and transform an input to a suitable output, not mutating the input and producing side effects. That's why there isn't a `Enumerable.ForEach` in C#.

Answer (score 2):

For `getFields()`, String concatenation is a not-unreasonable alternative you can consider. For `toString()`, using `delete()` is probably easier to read than the conditional check, there's probably no real performance gain due to branch prediction. It is distinctly wrong to merge the two methods. `getFields()` is probably not the best name, since it doesn't actually return the fields. Good names are hard, and nothing is jumping immediately to mind.

```
public abstract class Component {

    private String[] getFields() {
        final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();    
        for (final Field field: this.getClass().getFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                lines.add(field.getName() + " = " + field.get(this));
            } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
                lines.add(field.getName() + " > " + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
        }
        return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(this.getClass().getSimpleName());

        builder.append('(');

        for (final String field : this.getFields()) {
            builder.append(field);
            builder.append(", ");
        }
        builder.delete(builder.length() - 2, builder.length());

        builder.append(')');

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good suggestion on the String Concatenation. Instead of using `delete` you can do `return builder.substring(0, builder.length() - 2) + ')'`

Comment: Is there a reason that you have made all of the variables final?